# How to determine whether a string contains other strings?

Tags: javascript, chai

I went through the Chai documentation, but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

Is it possible to use Chai to determine, whether a string contains other strings?

I know that I can use it like the following:

```
expect('foobar').to.have.string('bar');
```

But how can I use it by feeding an array of strings to it like this:

```
expect('foobar').to.have.string(['foo', 'bar'])
```

Or just simply:

```
expect('foobar').to.contain.any([foo', 'bar'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `keys` assertion in this case:

```
expect('foobar').to.include.keys('foo', 'bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`match`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_string) for a regex OR check.

```
// PASS for response = "The service is down."
expect(response).to.match(/(down|up)/);
response.should.match(/(down|up)/);

// PASS for response = "The service is up now."
expect(response).to.match(/(down|up)/);
response.should.match(/(down|up)/);

// FAIL for response = ""The service is left or right""
expect(response).to.match(/(down|up)/);
response.should.match(/(down|up)/);
```